# Silverstripe: HolderPage without a link

Tags: silverstripe

Is there any way to create a page type that can be a parent to other pages, but doesn't have a link or any way to access it from the frontend?

Some kind of holder page for the backend.

-helenclarko

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try and hack the `Link()` method on this page class and return the parent's link.

```
public function Link()
{
    return $this->Parent()->Link();
}
```

Also disable the `URLSegment` field in `getCMSFields()`.

Comment: Thanks WMK, 
I'll need to try this out. 

Is there any way to return 404 or something like that?

Comment: @helenclarko return $this->httpError(404); will return a 404